# How to send a message by time in a datatimefield in DJANGO?

Tags: python, django

Hello everyone I am making a REST application based on Django Rest. I have a mailing model and fields with the start date and the end date of the mailing. I would like the newsletter to be sent by the value in the creation date field and completed in the end date field. I am a beginner, and I have no ideas about implementing such an idea. Could it be Celery?

```
class MailingList(models.Model):
        start_dt = models.DateTimeField()
        text = models.TextField(max_length=500)
        operator_code = models.ForeignKey(
            OperatorCode,
            related_name='+',
            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        )
        tag = models.ForeignKey(
            Tag,
            related_name='+',
            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        )
        end_dt = models.DateTimeField()
```

Comment: do you want to send it via email or with what? Celery used for tasks managing, it may do your code `asyncronious`, it has nothing to do with actually sending messages at first place

Comment: @oruchkin, i want send it in another app by rest in json format